# Where do I get weights for a Dutch-style cheese press?

Tags: cheese-making

Many cheesemaking suppliers sell [Dutch-style cheese presses](https://cheesemaking.com/collections/cheese-molds-and-presses/products/dutch-style-cheese-press), which are also among the easiest type to make yourself.  These apply pressure using weights hung at the end of the arm, or further up. However, no retailer who sells the press that I've tried (out of 6 different ones) also sells weights for it.

I suspect that is because the weights are expected to be easily obtainable locally wherever you are, but for the life of me I can't figure out how.  Where/how would you get appropriate weights for this kind of cheese press?

Comment: Bottle of water on a rope is weight.

Comment: ... and, easy-peasy, 1 litre of water weighs 1 kilogram :)

Comment: Wanna post that as an answer?

Comment: The local athletic shops sells iron barbell weights for $1 or so a pound. Wire them up with some 12 gauge wire through the central hole, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about weights specifically for this cheese press. However, as an avid fisherman I use weights designed to be hung off of various types of lines and/or clasps. While most are made of lead, you can get tungsten, stainless steel, and even rubber coated ones now. I have seen them up to 3lbs, mind you if you live near the ocean I am sure (almost certain) you could get larger.